# Unable to clone vector with deep copy of objects

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, clone

This is my vector that I want to fully clone (meaning that if I change the cloned vector it doesn't affect the original vector).

```
  var vector:Vector.<Path_Tiles> = new Vector.<Path_Tiles>();
  vector = path_finder.Find_Path(Gird.TILE_SET, start, end, R_G_B, SCAREDNESS);// return a vector of path_tiles in order
```

and I'm trying to put it into this vector

```
 var vector2:Vector.<Path_Tiles> = clone(vector);
```

and clone method is this (which I found this method on a website so I do not fully understand it)

```
   public function clone(source:Object):*
    {
        var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        myBA.writeObject(source);
        myBA.position = 0;
        return(myBA.readObject());
    }
```

But I'm getting this error: "[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert **AS3**.vec::Vector.@85973d1 to **AS3**.vec.Vector.."

How do I convert Path_Tiles into an object?

Comment: Your clone method must return same type of vector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RajneeshGaikwad Can you please do a quick example /(copy and paste my clone methods and change into a return of a vector) as i'm unsure how the clone method is working and all my versions of that are not working.

Comment: Are you referring to a shallow clone such as `concat()`, which your previous question is regarding; or, cloning copies of objects within your vector?

Comment: @JasonSturges this question is linked to my last question, and I learnt that concat() only copy the vector and not the stuff inside the vector which i'm trying to do with no much luck. which lead me into this clone method which works with arrays but not with vectors

Comment: @AdamEdney Just call `vector2 = clone(vector);`, and simply assure the class is registered before the writing in the byte array.

Comment: @JasonSturges i put the registered in path tile and i got rid of the loop, and did   vector2 = clone(vector);  but im still getting the same error ": Argument count mismatch on Path_Tiles(). Expected 5, got 0" for "line tilesCloned = byteArray.readObject() as Vector.<Path_Tiles>;"

Comment: @AdamEdney Your class constructor must accept default parameters, if parameters are required.  Answer updated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assure your `Path_Tiles` class has been [registered](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html):

```
flash.net.registerClassAlias("tld.domain.package.Path_Tiles", Path_Tiles);
```

Then, you may copy by serializing the data to a `ByteArray`:

```
var tiles:Vector.<Path_Tiles>;
var tilesCloned:Vector.<Path_Tiles>;

var byteArray = new ByteArray();
byteArray.writeObject(tiles);
byteArray.position = 0;
tilesCloned = byteArray.readObject() as Vector.<Path_Tiles>;
```

Cast the `readObject()` deserialization to `Vector.<Path_Tiles>` using the `as` keyword.

Constructors for objects serialized must accept default parameters.

To put this all together, say this was your `Path_Tiles` class:

**Path_Tiles.as**

```
package
{
public class Path_Tiles
{
    public function Path_Tiles(property1:String=null, property2:int=undefined) {
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    public var property1:String;
    public var property2:int;
}
}
```

Here is your main class, showing an example of deep cloning the `Path_Tiles` collection:

**Main.as**

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.registerClassAlias;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public function Main() {
        super();

        var source:Vector.<Path_Tiles> = new <Path_Tiles>[
            new Path_Tiles("Hello", 1),
            new Path_Tiles("World", 2)
        ];

        var cloned:Vector.<Path_Tiles> = clone(source);
    }

    public function clone(source:Vector.<Path_Tiles>):Vector.<Path_Tiles> {
        flash.net.registerClassAlias("Path_Tiles", Path_Tiles);
        var byteArray = new ByteArray();
        byteArray.writeObject(source);
        byteArray.position = 0;
        return byteArray.readObject() as Vector.<Path_Tiles>;
    }
}
}
```

Finally, we can see the object was deep copied; confirmed by memory address:

[image: vector-deep-copy]

Comment: updated my main question as it not working, I very much appreciating you trying to help me

Comment: will you marry me? All jokes aside thank you so much (you must think I'm stupid) You have been really helpful and I got it all working how it should be. now tomorrow I will research all about how this works and why. You been great. Thanks Again :)